# How to add a background sound to iPhone app

Tags: ios

I need to add a background sound in my application. Where I can add it and how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973902/play-mp3-files-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ios+play+audio+file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

Add the sound to your resource folder in xcode and then add this code to your code wherever you want the sound to play. (In a button click method for example)

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"NameOfSoundfile" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Just for mine understand I put this code, for example in my Appdelegate.m near applicationDidFinishLaunching? I not need a button.

Comment: Yes, you can put it in applicationDidFinishLaunching or maybe applicationDidBecomeActive.

Comment: There is no resource folder in XCode 4.

Comment: @olafure Then just create one. Easy.